# Fail to redirect to the previous page after authenticating the user login using passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, passport.js

[isLoggedin Middleware]
[image: 1]

[Routes]
[image: 2]

[login route and trying to authenticate using passport.js]
[image: 3]

```
module.exports.isLoggedin = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else {
        // store the url the users are requesting
        req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;
        req.flash('error', 'You must be signed in first!')
        req.session.save(function (err) {
            return res.redirect("/login");
        })
    }
}
```

```
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('users/login')
})

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureFlash: true,
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.returnTo);
    req.flash('success', 'Welcome back!');
    res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/campgrounds');
})
```

```
router.get('/:id/edit', isLoggedin, catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!campground) {
        req.flash('error', 'Cannot find that campground!')
        return res.redirect('/campgrounds')
    }
    res.render('campgrounds/edit', { campground });
}))
```

I added in a middleware called isLoggedIn and I saved req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl; and I passed in this middleware to 2 routes (get('/:id/edit'). This middleware should be triggered if I accessed the route.

I was meant to Redirect to the previous page after authentication using passport.js, but after I logged in, req.session.returnTo was shown as undefined...

req.session.returnTo should've been req.originalUrl but after I logged in and tried to redirect to the previous page, it turned out to be undefined and I've been struggling with this...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session not updating after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563237/session-not-updating-after-redirect)

Comment: hello! I tried that and my req.session.returnTo is still undefined :(

Comment: Please update the question with your changes.

Comment: I updated the code above ^

Comment: I explicitly added in the req.session.save method to the isLoggedin middleware, but it still does not work