# Retrieving hashed password from sql database

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, bcrypt

Having issues comparing user password and hashed password using bcrypt.I'll be glad if anyone helps.

Here is my login code snippet

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const searchSql2 = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ?'
  con.query(searchSql2,[username], async(err, results,fields) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  const hashedPassword = results[0].user_password
  const isValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, hashedPassword)
  if (isValid) {
    //password matched
    req.session.loggedin = true;
    req.session.username = username;
    res.redirect('./home')
    res.end();
  } else {
    res.send("Invalid username or password")
  }
  })
})
```

When user logins even with correct details he/she gets 'Invalid username or password!'.How do I go about this?

Comment: You set `req.session.loggedin = true`, but this is lost in the `res.redirect`. Use `req.session.save` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72564300/16462950).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session not updating after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563237/session-not-updating-after-redirect)