# Pino (pinojs) only logging some HTTP request

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, express-session, pinojs

I am trying to add logging with `pino` to an existing *node.js* web application, that uses *express.js* and *Postgresql*. However, some HTTP post request are not being logged. It seems to only happen with HTTP post request responding with a redirect. It also only happens then requesting by Safari. The problem does not occur then using Chrome or `curl`.

I am produced a minimal example here under, that reproduces the problem. As in my main project it does reproduce the problem when using Safari on my laptop, but not when using Chrome or `curl`. If I remove the usage of `connect-pg-simple` the problem disappears.

No error message what so ever is given.

```js
import { default as express } from 'express'
import { default as pinoHttp } from 'pino-http'
import { default as session } from 'express-session';
import { default as sessionStore } from 'connect-pg-simple';

import { default as pg } from 'pg';
const Pool = pg.Pool
const pool = new Pool()

const reqLogger = pinoHttp({
    level: 'info',
    enabled: true
})

const app = express()

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    name: 'sessionId',
    resave: false,
    rolling: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new (sessionStore(session))({
        pool: pool
    }),
    cookie: {
        secure: 'auto',
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    }
}))

app.use(reqLogger)

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const html = `
        <form method="POST" action="/">
            <div>
                <label for="floatingInput">Username</label>
                <input name="username" type="text" id="floatingInput">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
                <input name="password" type="password" id="floatingPassword">
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Log in</button>
        </form>`
    res.send(html)
})

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect('/')
})

app.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log('Server running')
})
```

Comment: Unclear if that helps, but sessions are not automatically saved upon a redirect, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72564300/16462950).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen it makes no different calling the function res.session.save as described in your link. It also would not explain the browser/client dependency.