# Session data doesn't get stored, so authentication fails

Tags: node.js, express

In my express app I am doing registering and authentication well on localhost:3000
After I deployed it authentication fails. I console.log'ged' the req.session.userId after logging in which gives me a proper id. As a result I am authorized to make a new post, but as soon as I click on the link to new post I get redirected back to the home page.
I am a little bit confused with sessions and cookies and I am not sure which one persists between different routs and which not.
index.js:

```js
const session = require('express-session')


app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 120000 },
  resave: false
}))

app.use("*", (req, res, next) => {
    loggedIn = req.session.userId;
    next()
});

app.use(flash());

app.get('/posts/new', authMiddleware, newPostController)

app.post('/posts/store', authMiddleware, storePostController)

app.post('/users/register', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, storeUserController)

app.get('/auth/login', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, loginController)
```

authMiddleware.js:

```js
const User = require('../models/User')

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.session.userId)
    .then((user) => {
      console.log(req.session.userId);
      if(!user ) { return res.redirect('/') }
      next()
    })
    .catch((error) => { 
      return res.redirect('/') })
}
```

loginUser.js:

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const User = require('../models/User')

module.exports = (req, res) =>{
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  req.session.message = [];
  req.flash('data', req.body);
  console.log(req.body);
  User.findOne({ username: username })
    .then((user) => {
      if(user) {
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, same) => {
          if(same) {
            req.session.userId = user._id
            res.redirect('/')
          }
          else {
            if(password === "") {
              req.session.message[1] = "Provide Password"
        }
            else { req.session.message[1] = "Password is incorrect" }
            req.flash('message', req.session.message);
            res.redirect('/auth/login')
          }
        })
      }
      else {
        if(username === "" && password === "") {
        req.session.message = ["Provide Username", "Provide Password"];
    }
    else if(username === "") {
      req.session.message[0] = ["Provide Username"]
    }
    else {
      req.session.message[0] = "Username is incorrect"
    }
        req.flash('message', req.session.message);
        res.redirect('/auth/login')
      }
    })
}
```

Here is the app.cyclic.sh log:

```
App listening on port 5000
 { username: 'Nacy', password: '1111' }
 Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-10-06T09:25:52.388Z,
    originalMaxAge: 120000,
    httpOnly: true
  },
  message: [],
  flash: { data: [ [Object] ] },
  userId: '650bde898e3d6b08b6b876e3'
}
 undefined
 Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-10-06T09:25:57.165Z,
    originalMaxAge: 120000,
    httpOnly: true
  }
}
 Listening ...
```

I'd like to point out that or rare occasions req.session.userId does persist with the request to new post get request but that happens one in thirty attempts. On those rare occasions I can see the right id being printed to console. Then I fill in the form for new post and click a submit button which is post request but that fails with 100% probability. Of 20 times that I tried to save a post none of them got saved to Mongo Atlas.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session not updating after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563237/session-not-updating-after-redirect)

Comment: I will check it tomorrow, thank you.

Comment: I tried to do req.session.save() with callback in my loginUser.js controller immediately after I set the req.session.userId. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the issue. I also tried combining your recommendations with those Bartek offered in his answer but it didn't work out either. I would actually like to share the editions to code I made with you, but I am not sure how. I guess answering my question to provide code is a bad idea.

Comment: in loginUser.js now I have: ```bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, same) => {
          if(same) {
            req.session.userId = user._id
            req.session.save(function(err) {
            if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
            else res.redirect("/");
          });
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing might be due to the way sessions and cookies are handled in different environments. When you're running your app locally, your browser and server are on the same machine, so cookies and sessions are easily shared. However, when you deploy your app, your server and client are on different machines, and cookies might not be shared as expected due to security restrictions.

Here are a few things you can check:

1. Secure Cookies: If your production environment is using HTTPS (which it should), you need to set the secure option of your session cookie to true. This tells the browser to only send the cookie over HTTPS.

   ```
     app.use(session({
     secret: 'keyboard cat',
     saveUninitialized: true,
     cookie: { 
       maxAge: 120000,
       secure: true, // Add this line
       httpOnly: true // And this line if it's not already there
     },
     resave: false
   }))
   ```
2. SameSite Cookies: Some browsers require the SameSite attribute to be set for cookies. This attribute can have one of three values: Strict, Lax, or None. If it's set to Strict, the cookie will only be sent if the request is being made from the same site. This is a common source of problems when deploying apps, because your server and client are now on different sites.

   ```
            app.use(session({
            secret: 'keyboard cat',
            saveUninitialized: true,
            cookie: { 
                maxAge: 120000,
                secure: true,
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: 'none' // Add this line
                    },
                resave: false
             }))
   ```
3. Domain and Path: If your server and client are on different subdomains, you might need to set the domain and path options of your cookie.

   ```
   app.use(session({
   secret: 'keyboard cat',
   saveUninitialized: true,
   cookie: { 
      maxAge: 120000,
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      domain: '.yourdomain.com', // Add this line
      path: '/' // And this line
           },
      resave: false
   }))
   ```

Remember to replace .yourdomain.com with your actual domain.

4. Trust Proxy: If your app is running behind a proxy (like Nginx), you need to tell Express to trust the proxy.

   ```
    app.set('trust proxy', 1) // Add this line
    app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { 
    maxAge: 120000,
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'none',
    domain: '.yourdomain.com',
    path: '/'
    },
     resave: false
    }))
   ```

Please try these suggestions and see if they solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tomorrow I will be checking your suggestions!

Comment: I started adding the lines you suggested incrementally step by step. In step number one you suggested to add two lines. After I do it the id never appears in console logs after submitting the login form. Getting rid of the secure and httpOnly options one at a time, I found out that it's specifically the secure: true that's causing the id not to be saved.

Comment: I then proceeded with adding sameSite, domain and path but nothing helped. The values I used were exactly as you suggested: ```app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { 
   maxAge: 120000,
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'none',
    domain: '.fuzzy-cod-lapel.cyclic.cloud.com',
    path: '/'
  },
  resave: false
}))
```

Comment: It's weird that the result varies if you make dozens of attempts. Before trying any of yours when I submit the login form my navbar accomodates to show the New Post link 100% of time. So I got that covered. The problem is when I hit the New Post menu item. Roughly I get redirected to the home page 29 of 30 times. And that one time is when I am actually served the new post form. What's going on in console is the console does log the id before serving the new post form(it's that one time out of 30) or it just says undefined when I am not served the new post form and instead get the home page.

Comment: I find this inconsistency weird. Could it be that I use promises wrong in some way?

Comment: Should I explicitly use some session store instead of default MemoryStore?