# Logical issue with OAuth 2.0 Implementation in React App - Redirect After Successful Login Not Working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am currently working on implementing OAuth 2.0 in my React application for user authorization. To achieve this, I have set up a custom Auth Provider with all the necessary configurations, such as the client ID and client secret.

Here's the flow of my implementation:

I belive after login my redirect url will call to get token and validation ** here /login

In my React app, I have a "Login" button that appears when no user is logged in.Here i want to  redirect to /dashboard after successfull login with userdetails.I am also using react-router-dom.once i loged in i can see in my browser like  http://127.0.0.1:3000/login?code=4up1z0ttQNNi5vCFUxkPqV-SOQqEIzAnYDIAAAH1&state=40ddfc08591ab2819f4b675ce75090ff  after this /login not even hit

When a user clicks the "Login" button, they are redirected to the authorization server's login page. At this point, they are prompted to sign in to their account if they haven't already done so.

After providing the correct credentials, the authorization server redirects the user back to my app, providing it with an access token that allows the app to access user information.

With the access token, my React app can make API calls on behalf of the user, as long as those requests are within the scope of the permissions granted.

I'm using the Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) for this implementation.

The problem I'm facing is that after a successful login on the authorization server's page, the redirect URL specified in my configuration is not being called, and the code flow seems to stop.Not calling the token url and getting token. I've been trying to troubleshoot this issue for several days but haven't been able to identify the problem.Could anyone please help me identify the issue and provide proper guidance on how to resolve it? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Below is the relevant code snippet for my implementation:

My node js Back end

```
// .env
APP_PORT=3001
BASE_URL=https://MyAuthProvider.com
CLIENT_ID=12345wed
CLIENT_SECRET=abcd
REDIRECT_URI=http://127.0.0.1:3000/login
LOGOUT_URI=http://127.0.0.1:3000/logout
AUTHORIZATION_URL=/authorization.oauth2
TOKEN_URL=/as/token.oauth2
USERINFO_URL=/userinfo.openid
INTROSPECTION_CLIENT_ID=3456efgh
INTROSPECTION_CLIENT_SECRET=efghi
INTROSPECTION_URL=/introspect.oauth2

// server.js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const config = require('./config');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const axios = require('axios');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const winston = require('winston');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [ new winston.transports.Console() ],
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp(),
        winston.format.printf(({ timestamp, level, message }) => {
            return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message}`;
        })
    )
});

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: [ 'http://127.0.0.1:3000', 'http://localhost:3000' ],
        methods: [ 'GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE' ],
        credentials: true
    })
);

const codeChallengeMethod = 'S256';

const generateCodeChallenge = (codeVerifier) => {
    return crypto
        .createHash('sha256')
        .update(codeVerifier)
        .digest('base64')
        .replace(/\+/g, '-')
        .replace(/\//g, '_')
        .replace(/=/g, '');
};

const validateAccessToken = async (accessToken) => {
    try {
        const introspectionResponse = await axios.post(`${config.BASE_URL}${config.INTROSPECTION_URL}`, {
            client_id: config.INTROSPECTION_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: config.INTROSPECTION_CLIENT_SECRET,
            token: accessToken
        });

        return introspectionResponse.data.active;
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Error validating access token:', error);
        return false;
    }
};

const generateRandomStateAndNonce = (req, res, next) => {
    req.state = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    req.nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    next();
};

const generateCodeVerifierAndChallenge = (req, res, next) => {
    req.codeVerifier = crypto
        .randomBytes(32)
        .toString('base64')
        .replace(/\+/g, '-')
        .replace(/\//g, '_')
        .replace(/=/g, '');
    req.codeChallenge = generateCodeChallenge(req.codeVerifier);
    next();
};

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
    cookieSession({
        name: 'sess',
        secret: 'asdfgh',
        httpOnly: true,
        credentials: true
    })
);

const PORT = config.APP_PORT || process.env.PORT;

app.get('/AuthPage', generateRandomStateAndNonce, generateCodeVerifierAndChallenge, (req, res) => {
    const scope = 'openid profile group_type authorization_group offline_access';
    const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent(config.REDIRECT_URI);
    const clientID = config.CLIENT_ID;

    const authUrl = `${config.BASE_URL}${config.AUTHORIZATION_URL}?client_id=${clientID}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scope}&state=${req.state}&nonce=${req.nonce}&response_type=code&acr_values=myauth:idp:gas:strong&code_challenge=${req.codeChallenge}&code_challenge_method=${codeChallengeMethod}`;

    console.log('authUrl-dev', authUrl);
    logger.info('Authorization URL generated', { authUrl });
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.state);
    res.cookie('nonce', req.nonce);

    // Send the authUrl in the JSON response
    res.json({ url: authUrl });
});

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const state = req.headers['x-xsrf-token'];

    try {
        const codeChallenge = req.body.code_challenge;
        const codeChallengeMethod = req.body.code_challenge_method;

        const response = await axios.post(`${config.BASE_URL}${config.TOKEN_URL}`, {
            client_id: config.CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: config.CLIENT_SECRET,
            code: req.body.code,
            redirect_uri: config.REDIRECT_URI,
            state: state,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            code_challenge: codeChallenge,
            code_challenge_method: codeChallengeMethod
        });

        if (response.data.access_token) {
            const isAccessTokenValid = await validateAccessToken(response.data.access_token);

            if (isAccessTokenValid) {
                req.session.token = response.data.access_token;

                // Redirect to /dashboard after successful login
                res.redirect('/dashboard');
            } else {
                res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
            }
        } else {
            res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Error during login:', error);
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
});

app.get('/getUserDetails', async (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.token) {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${config.BASE_URL}${config.USERINFO_URL}`, {
                headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${req.session.token}` }
            });
            res.cookie('login', response.data.login, { httpOnly: true });

            logger.info('getUserDetails succeeded:', { userDetails: response.data });

            res.send(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error('Error in getUserDetails:', { error });
            res.status(500).send(error.message);
        }
    } else {
        res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
    }
});

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.clearCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
    res.clearCookie('login');
    res.redirect(config.LogoutURI);
});

app.get('/logged_in', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const token = req.cookies.token;
        if (!token) {
            return res.json({ loggedIn: false });
        }

        jwt.verify(token, config.CLIENT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ loggedIn: false });
            } else {
                const newToken = jwt.sign({ user: decoded.user }, config.CLIENT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '3000s' });
                res.cookie('token', newToken, { maxAge: 300000, httpOnly: true });
                res.json({ loggedIn: true, user: decoded.user });
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ loggedIn: false });
    }
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    logger.info(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

// React Frontend
// App.js

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import Home from './Home';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';
import { AuthContextProvider } from './AuthContext';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <AuthContextProvider>
                    <Router>
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                            <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
                            <Route path="/loginpage" element={<LoginPage />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </Router>
                </AuthContextProvider>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

// AuthContext.js

import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3001';
const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(null);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    const checkLoginState = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${serverUrl}/logged_in`);

            console.log('response:  ', response);
            if (response.data.loggedIn === false) {
                // Handle when the user is not logged in
                setLoggedIn(false);
                setUser(null);
            } else {
                const { loggedIn: loggedInValue, user } = response.data;
                setLoggedIn(loggedInValue);
                if (user) setUser(user);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        checkLoginState();
    }, [checkLoginState]);

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, checkLoginState, user }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export { AuthContext, AuthContextProvider };

// Home.js

import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContext } from './AuthContext';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';

const Home = () => {
    const { loggedIn } = useContext(AuthContext);

    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={loggedIn === true ? <Dashboard /> : <LoginPage />} />
        </Routes>
    );
};

export default Home;

// LoginPage.js

import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3001';

const LoginPage = () => {
    const handleLogin = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${serverUrl}/AuthPage`);
            const { url } = response.data;
            window.location.assign(url);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Login to Dashboard</h3>
            <button className="btn" onClick={handleLogin}>
                Login
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoginPage;

dashbord.js

import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { AuthContext } from './AuthContext';

const Dashboard = () => {
    const { user, loggedIn, checkLoginState } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [ posts, setPosts ] = useState([]);

    const serverUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL;

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const fetchPosts = async () => {
                if (loggedIn === true) {
                    try {
                        const response = await axios.get(`${serverUrl}/getUserDetails`);
                        setPosts(response.data.posts);
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                }
            };

            fetchPosts();
        },
        [ loggedIn, serverUrl ]
    );

    const handleLogout = async () => {
        try {
            await axios.post(`${serverUrl}/auth/logout`);
            checkLoginState();
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Dashboard</h3>
            <button className="btn" onClick={handleLogout}>
                Logout
            </button>
            <h4>{user ? user.name : 'User Name'}</h4>
            <br />
            <p>{user ? user.email : 'User Email'}</p>
            <br />
            <img src={user ? user.picture : ''} alt={user ? user.name : 'User'} />
            <br />
            <div>
                <h4>Posts</h4>
                <ul>{posts.map((post) => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)}</ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Your `app.post('/login', ...)` does not contain the necessary redirect to `/dashboard`.

Comment: i have tried to give  redirect /dashboard in /login. but the problem is once i loged in i can see in my browser like  ''http://127.0.0.1:3000/login?code=4up1z0ttQNNi5vCFUxkPqV-SOQqEIzAnYDIAAAH1&state=40ddfc08591ab2819f4b675ce75090ff''  after this /login not even hit

Comment: Please share the code of your attempt to give a redirect to `/dashboard`.

Comment: above context i have shared all the code in description.both back end and front end  code added

Comment: I don't see a statement in your code that would cause a redirect to `/dashboard`.

Comment: i updated /login end point in server.js.there i am redirecting but /login is not hitting bu redirect url as i said in description

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong here.

According to the [OpenID Connect specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthResponse), the authorization servers issues a GET redirect, not a POST redirect. Your middleware function must therefore use `app.get("/login", ...)`.

GET requests do not have a `req.body`, instead the parameters come in the `/login` URL and must be addressed like `req.query.code`, not `req.body.code`. The statements

```js
const codeChallenge = req.body.code_challenge;
const codeChallengeMethod = req.body.code_challenge_method;
```

do not make sense either, because the `/login` URL does not contain these parameters. Is your authorization server correctly configured for PKCE?

The middleware function must, if the token request was successful, store the token in the session and then redirect the browser to the intended page, in your case `/dashboard`. Note that this requires an explicit call to `req.session.save`, because [sessions are not automatically saved after a redirect.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563237/session-not-updating-after-redirect)

```js
app.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
  ...
  if (isAccessTokenValid) {
    req.session.token = response.data.access_token;
    req.session.save(function(err) {
      if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
      else res.redirect("/dashboard");
    });
  } else {
    ...
});
```

Comment: but after successfull login the end point -/login not being called.i can see in the browser url like -http://127.0.0.1:45555/login?code=4up1z0ttQNNi5vCFUxkPqV-SOQqEIzAnYDIAAAH1&state=40ddfc08591ab2819f4b675ce75090ff  and the page is white.in log i couldnt see /login is called.

Comment: I think you need `app.get` instead of `app.post`, see my edited answer.

Comment: that i have alredy tried but still same  :(   /login is not calling

Comment: How do you know that "/login is not hit"? What does the browser display when the address bar contains http://127.0.0.1:3000/login?code=4up1z0ttQNNi5vCFUxkPqV-SOQqEIzAnYDIAAAH1&state=40ddfc08591ab2819f4b675ce75090ff?

Comment: in /login end point i  console and inside that only my token creation end point is there .if no token response is coming like isloggedin=false. browser display a white page only and in the console loged in false and no token created

Comment: after successfull login my browser be like 

https://ibb.co/5ntr6wc

Comment: UPDATE: i am now inside the /login but  getting socket hang up error.not generating token

Comment: "What could be the reason for encountering a 'Socket Hang Up' error when dealing with OAuth 2.0 Redirect URL Issue in a React App and Node.js Backend, despite successfully receiving a response in Postman, especially when using Node.js POST method?"