How to store session data in express properly
I have a 4.x express app. I would like to store data in the session after user has successfully logged in. When I try to access this data in another request the data is always undefined.
Here is my code :
 app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure : false,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 3600000
    }
    
    
}));

After logIn I put the data into the session:
req.session.verficationCode = 123;

In each subsequent request the session data is lost ?

How do you finish the response after putting data into the session? Note that sessions are not updated after a redirect (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563237/session-not-updating-after-redirect).

I dont use a Redirect. Just send the json response to the client

When I use Postman I am able to login and call another request where the session id remains the same. If I use my Ember App for each request a new session is created. Seems that Ember App does not send the cookie back to the server
